# How to configure RSA HSM private and public key in microsoft azure vault?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, hsm, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have to configure RSA HSM Public and private key in the azure key vault and save the data in encrypted form.

Answer (score 1):

For added assurance, when you use Azure Key Vault, you can import or generate keys in hardware security modules (HSMs) that never leave the HSM boundary. This scenario is often referred to as bring your own key, or BYOK. The HSMs are FIPS 140-2 Level 2 validated. Azure Key Vault uses nCipher nShield family of HSMs to protect your keys.

More information about generating and transferring an HSM-protected key over the Internet:

- You generate the key from an offline workstation, which reduces the attack surface.
- The key is encrypted with a Key Exchange Key (KEK), which stays encrypted until it is transferred to the Azure Key Vault HSMs. Only the encrypted version of your key leaves the original workstation.
- The toolset sets properties on your tenant key that binds your key to the Azure Key Vault security world. So after the Azure Key Vault HSMs receive and decrypt your key, only these HSMs can use it. Your key cannot be exported. This binding is enforced by the nCipher HSMs.
- The Key Exchange Key (KEK) that is used to encrypt your key is generated inside the Azure Key Vault HSMs and is not exportable. The HSMs enforce that there can be no clear version of the KEK outside the HSMs. In addition, the toolset includes attestation from nCipher that the KEK is not exportable and was generated inside a genuine HSM that was manufactured by nCipher.
- The toolset includes attestation from nCipher that the Azure Key Vault security world was also generated on a genuine HSM manufactured by nCipher. This attestation proves to you that Microsoft is using genuine hardware.
- Microsoft uses separate KEKs and separate Security Worlds in each geographical region. This separation ensures that your key can be used only in data centers in the region in which you encrypted it. For example, a key from a European customer cannot be used in data centers in North American or Asia.

For implementing bring your own key (BYOK) , please visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-hsm-protected-keys)

Hope it helps.